# jquery autosuggest ui conditional return statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery autosuggest ui. and it works fine. However, is that possible
to have conditional return statement. If I do that my jquery blows up.

```
response ($.map( data.data, function(item){
    return {
        if (item.secT = '') {
            label: item.bodydata+" ("+item.desc+") ",
            value: item.bodydata+" ("+item.stringid+") ",
        }else {
            label: item.bodydata+" ("+item.desc+") " +" ("+item.sec+") ",
            value: item.bodydata+" ("+item.stringid+") ",
        };
    }
```

Comment: Your syntax is broken. You can't do that with JS.

Comment: @erik: Finbarr is correct, run your code through http://www.jslint.com and you'll get (several) syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are all over the place. Change it to this:

```
response ($.map( data.data, function(item){
    return
        item.secT == '' ? {
            label: item.bodydata+" ("+item.desc+") ",
            value: item.bodydata+" ("+item.stringid+") "
        } : {
            label: item.bodydata+" ("+item.desc+") " +" ("+item.sec+") ",
            value: item.bodydata+" ("+item.stringid+") "
        }
}));
```

Comment: sorry the it was just an indentation

Comment: still getting this error , If I remove the condition and just output than i do not get this error

Comment: @eric: I made a mistake there. `item.secT = ''` should have been `item.secT == ''`. I updated my code.